# Nuxt. Trying to use apollo-graphql I get several errors that I didn't get with just vue

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, vue-apollo

I have integrated apollo-graphql in vue (without nuxt)and it worked.

But now I am trying to start with Nuxt.
In folder plugins I have included a js file with apollo initialization.

Then in a vue file I import the file with: `import '~/plugins/apollo-client'` (I got the idea from here: [Apollo, GraphQL, Vue and Nuxt shenanigans](https://github.com/esclapes/coosto-hackathon/blob/master/app/src/pages/index.vue) )

I am getting plenty of errors like not being able to use localStorage.
For that I have installed a package called npm i nuxt-storage.

But then at the split command:

```
const link = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query)
    return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription'
  }, 
  wsLink,
  httpLink,
)
```

I get this error: `Cannot read property 'request' of null`

I am afraid that I am going to be getting more errors after this one is solved.

What am I doing wrong?

Where should I place the code that I had in main.js?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using nuxt-apollo, it should be better.

The error you got must have been due to the lack of step.

```
npm i @nuxtjs/apollo &&
npm install --save @nuxtjs/apollo
# if you are using *.gql or *.graphql files add graphql-tag to your dependencies 
npm install --save graphql-tag
```

1. You'll need to set up your config as you've stated above,

   In `nuxt.config.js`:

   ```
   export default {
     ...
     modules: ['@nuxtjs/apollo'],
     apollo: {
       clientConfigs: {
         default: {
           httpEndpoint: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/cj1dqiyvqqnmj0113yuqamkuu' //link to your graphql backend.
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Make your query

   In `gql/allCars.gql`:

   ```
   {
     allCars {
       id
       make
       model
       year
     }
   }
   ```
3. Use graphql in your component

   In `pages/index.vue`:

   ```
   <script>
   import allCars from '~/apollo/queries/allCars'
   export default {
     apollo: {
       allCars: {
         prefetch: true,
         query: allCars
       }
     },
     head: {
       title: 'Cars with Apollo'
     }
   }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I finally moved the project to quasar.

Comment: The first two npm commands are redundant.